# Rails 7: Nested resources/forms not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, nested-routes

i have three models:

```
class Checklist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :page
    has_many :groups

    has_rich_text :description

#   validates_presence_of :title
end



class Group < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :checklist
end


class Page < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :checklists
    has_rich_text :description
end
```

A page can have one or many checklists.
A Checklist can have one or more Groups.

All Associations are created.

On the pages editpage i created a form like this:

```
 <% @page.checklists.each do |cl| %>

    <%= form_with(model: [@page, cl]) do |f| %>

        .... more code => text fields etc

    <% end %>

    <% end %>
```

And the checklist controller:

```
def create

    @page = Page.find(params[:page_id])

    @checklist = @page.checklists.build

   

    if @checklist.save

      notice = nil

    else

      notice = @checklist.errors.full_messages.join('.') << '.'

    end

    redirect_to edit_page_path(@page), notice: notice

  end
```

There I can easily create a checklist for this page.

Now i want to do the same with groups for checklists. But there is my problem, it won't work.

Here is the form:

```
<%= form_for [@page, @checklist, @group] do |form|%>
    ... more code => text fields etc
<% end %>
```

This is my create action for groups:

```
def create
@page = Page.find(params[:page_id])
@checklist = Page.checklists.find(params[:checklist_id])
@group = @checklist.groups.build

if @group.save
    notice = nil
else
    notice =  @group.errors.full_messages.join('.') << '.'
end
    redirect_to edit_page_checklist_path(@checklist), notice: notice
end
```

Is there any other code needed to help me?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
@checklist = Page.checklists.find(params[:checklist_id])
```

doesn't make much sense. Instead, it needs to be

```
@checklist = @page.checklists.find(params[:checklist_id])
```

because you only want to find checklists that are associated with the page found in the setup before.

Sidenote: With [shallow nesting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) in the `routes.rb` the setup would be a bit simpler. Because the checklist's id is already unique in the database, therefore the page id is not needed in this case.